# Javassist insertbefore line number incorrect

Tags: java, logback, instrumentation, javassist

I'm injecting a logback logger into jars using Javassist.

In the pattern of logger, I'm recording line number among other details like time, thread, file etc.

The line number of generated log is correct when injected using `ctMethod.insertAfter()`. But when injected using `ctMethod.insertbefore()`, the line number is recorded as `-1`.

Why does this happen? And how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Javassist does itself not add any line number information to its code. Within Java byte code, line number information is expressed via information about the start of a line. As Javassist does not change or add such information, it appears as if the `insertAfter` code is placed on the last line whereas no information is available for the `insertBefore` code.

Given some method `foo`, Javassist would add the code as in the following pseudo code example:

```
void foo() {
  // inserted before - in line number information
  // start line number 1
  // original code
  // start line number 2
  // original code
  // inserted after - still on line number 2
}
```

As the offset is now placed after the `insertBefore` code, the latter code does not imply any line number information (expressed by the value `-1`). As the `insertAfter` code is implicitly placed after the last offset, it appears as if it was placed within the last line.

You can avoid this by adding code at the respective line where Javassist adds the code [after the line number information using `insertAt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899518/modifying-line-numbers-in-javassist).  Alternatively, you can use Byte Buddy for code manipulation where you can add code using the `Advice` component. The `insertBefore` equivalent is the `@OnMethodEnter` annotation which [takes a property `prependLineNumber`](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.6.9/net/bytebuddy/asm/Advice.OnMethodEnter.html#prependLineNumber--) which does do what you want. It is set to `true` by default.